# Ошибка MongoDB Error: can't connect to new replica set master

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.q0502.mongodb.net/test" --username admin-sergey
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
Enter password: Cannot get console mode 6
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00.q0502.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.q0502.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.q0502.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=atlas-7cei3e-shard-0&ssl=true


*** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

Error: can't connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-02.q0502.mongodb.net:27017], err: AuthenticationFailed: Missing expected field "pwd" :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Comment: Вопросы принято задавать на русском языке и в более развернутом виде

Comment: а зачем вам mongo кластер?

Comment: В ошибке вед ясно написано: "необходимо добавить  ip-адрес в список разрешенных"

Comment: "а зачем вам mongo кластер?" -  ну я учусь и мы делаем сайт с базами данных на mongo.

Comment: по поводу ip адреса- не уверен как вставить скрин в комментарий, но в закладке

Comment: ...ip access list значитсяб что  мой текущий ip включён

Comment: Решение нашёл на англоязычной версии Stackoverflow. Нужно в строку сразу добавить пароль    --password xxxxx